# Chef-Client fails to get the ruby gem during chef provisioning

Tags: ruby, docker, chef-infra

I am following the chef blog: https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/11/12/chef-provisioning-infrastructure-as-code/
On trying the command 
`chef-client -z <myenv>.rb`, it fails with the following exception

```html
Running handlers:
[2015-05-12T08:58:25-07:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-05-12T08:58:25-07:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-05-12T08:58:25-07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /scratch/ChefWorkstation/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.536536008 seconds
[2015-05-12T08:58:25-07:00] ERROR: cannot load such file -- chef/provisioning/docker_driver
[2015-05-12T08:58:27-07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

If i try,
`chef gem list` and `chef gem which chef/provisioning/docker_driver` shows the gem listed and the path respectively

Can somebody please help here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was running the command as sudo. But if I do not use sudo I see docker issues. However, this problem is resolved